# Azure Active Directory Graph vs Microsoft Graph

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, asp.net-web-api2, azure-ad-graph-api

Can Anyone tell the difference between Azure Active Directory Graph vs Microsoft Graph.

What is the use of the these API and appropriate scenario to choose these API

Also What is the best approach to call the Graph API (directly from angular application or From Web API)?

Comment: Hi Karuna, both of juunas and me have provided an answer for this question. If it helps your problem, could you please mark one of the answers as "accepted", thanks~

Comment: I think some problem with my account not able to perform accept

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [tutorial](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/) which about the difference between AAD Graph and Microsoft Graph.

Currently, we'd rather you use Microsoft Graph but not AAD Graph because some features are migrating from AAD Graph to Microsoft Graph. But in some case, we can just implement the requirements by AAD Graph.

And in my opinion, we can just call the Graph API directly from angular application easily.

Answer (score 1):

> Can Anyone tell the difference between Azure Active Directory Graph vs Microsoft Graph.

AAD Graph API is an older API that gives access to only directory data. 
You should prefer MS Graph API wherever possible. 
MS Graph API combines many APIs into one, including those in AAD Graph API.

> What is the use of the these API and appropriate scenario to choose these API

Always choose MS Graph API if it works in your case and provides the data you need. 
For example with Azure AD B2C you cannot really use MS Graph API. 
There may also be some smaller things missing from MS Graph API that exist in AAD Graph API.

> Also What is the best approach to call the Graph API (directly from angular application or From Web API)?

Use Implicit Grant flow with MSAL.js from your front-end. 
Your front-end app needs to be registered in AAD and require delegated permissions to the API so it can call the API on behalf of the signed in user.